# way to write a query into datatable select

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, datatable

how to write a query

```
Select Top 1 from tablename
OrderBy Desc
```

into

Datatable 
i have a code as:

```
DataRow[] ClassDetail = dt.Select("TOP 1 DESC");
```

but it doesn't execute.Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use linq for this

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
```

option 1:

```
List<DataRow> rows1 = dt.Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>().OrderByDescending(a => a["MyColumn"]).Take(1).ToList();
```

option 2:

```
List<DataRow> rows2 = dt.AsEnumerable().OrderByDescending(a => a["MyColumn"]).Take(1).ToList();
```

Comment: +1 You can do the order by in `Select()`, but Linq is afaik the only way to emulate a `TOP` query from a datatable.